# How to get to get claims from JWT token without validation in Go

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

I have a JWT token with the claims below

```
{
  "authorized": true,
  "email": "sample@gmail.com",
  "exp": 1589929351,
  "node": "/auth/nodes0000000023",
  "role": "admin"
}
```

The issuer of the JWT is the `claims['node']`. In the above claims it is the `/auth/nodes0000000023`.
How do I extract the issuer from the token without verifying the token. 
I want to get the issuer name so that I can go find his `publicKey` from a `map` and then verify the token.

I have found the function `func (*Parser) ParseUnverified` in the docs, but it is unclear on how to use it.

The library used is `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`

Comment: it can be good idea to post library you use to parse JWT tokens

Comment: ohh forgot it, thnx mate

Comment: You use it the same way you use parse: `tok,_,er=ParseUnverified(tokenString,&claimsStruct)`

Comment: Thanks it worked, you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unverified parse API the same way you use the verified API:

```
tok,_,err := p.ParseUnverified(tokenString,&claimsStruct)
```